# Stop Training in Keras when Accuracy is already 1.0

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

How will I stop Keras Training when the accuracy already reached 1.0? I tried monitoring loss value, but I haven't tried stopping the training when the accuracy is already 1.

I tried the code below with no luck:

```
stopping_criterions =[
    EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=0, patience = 1000),
    EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', base_line=1.0, patience =0)

]

model.summary()
model.compile(Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(scaled_train_samples, train_labels, batch_size=1000, epochs=1000000, callbacks=[stopping_criterions], shuffle = True, verbose=2)
```

UPDATE:

The training immediately stops at first epoch, even if the accuracy is still not `1.0`.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: please check Keras callback.EarlyStopping https://keras.io/callbacks/ , try setting early stopping on val_acc

Answer (score 18):

**Update:** tested in keras 2.4.3 (Dec.2020)

I don't know why `EarlyStopping` does not work in this case. Instead, I defined a custom callback that stops training when `acc` (or `val_acc`) reaches a specified baseline:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class TerminateOnBaseline(Callback):
    """Callback that terminates training when either acc or val_acc reaches a specified baseline
    """
    def __init__(self, monitor='accuracy', baseline=0.9):
        super(TerminateOnBaseline, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.baseline = baseline

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        acc = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if acc is not None:
            if acc >= self.baseline:
                print('Epoch %d: Reached baseline, terminating training' % (epoch))
                self.model.stop_training = True
```

You can use it like this:

```
callbacks = [TerminateOnBaseline(monitor='accuracy', baseline=0.8)]
callbacks = [TerminateOnBaseline(monitor='val_accuracy', baseline=0.95)]
```

---

**Note: This solution does not work.**

If you want to stop training when the training (or validation) accuracy exactly reaches 100%, then use `EarlyStopping` callback and set the `baseline` argument to 1.0 and `patience` to zero:

```
EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', baseline=1.0, patience=0)  # use 'val_acc' instead to monitor validation accuarcy
```

Comment: Ive tried your answer but it fails. Please see my update post :)

Comment: @Eliyah Sorry! I did not test that solution. I have updated my answer and added another solution which I have tested and is guaranteed to work. Please take a look.

Comment: just to mention, it should be 'val_accuracy'.

Comment: EarlyStopping works well. https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/

Answer (score 12):

Using an EarlyStopping with baseline callback doesn't do the trick here as far as I know.
'Baseline' is the min value of the monitored variable(here accuracy) that you should get to continue the training. Here the Baseline is 1.0, at the end of first epoch the Baseline is less than 'accuracy'(obviously you can't expect 'accuracy' of 1.0 at the first epoch itself) and since the patience is set to zero, the training stops at the first epoch itself since the Baseline is greater than accuracy. 
Using a custom callback does the work here.

```
class MyThresholdCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, threshold):
        super(MyThresholdCallback, self).__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None): 
        accuracy = logs["acc"]
        if accuracy >= self.threshold:
            self.model.stop_training = True
```

And calling the callback in the model.fit

```
callback=MyThresholdCallback(threshold=1.0)
model.fit(scaled_train_samples, train_labels, batch_size=1000, epochs=1000000, callbacks=[callback], shuffle = True, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 5):

The name `baseline` is misleading. Although not easy to interpret from the source code below, `baseline` should be understood as:

*While the monitored value is worse<sup>1</sup> than the baseline, keep training for max `patience` epochs longer. If it's better, elevate the baseline and repeat.*

<sub><sup>1</sup> i.e. lower for accuracies, higher for losses.</sub>

---

The relevant (trimmed) source code of `EarlyStopping`:

```py
self.best = baseline  # in initialization
...
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
  current = self.get_monitor_value(logs)
  if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):  # read as `current > self.best` (for accuracy)
     self.best = current
     self.wait = 0
  else:
     self.wait += 1
     if self.wait >= self.patience:
        self.model.stop_training = True
```

Then your example 
`EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', base_line=1.0, patience=0)` means: while the monitored value is worse than 1.0 (which it always is), keep training for 0 epochs longer (i.e. terminate immediately).

---

If you want these semantics:
*While the monitored value is worse than the baseline, keep training. If it is better, keep training until no progress is made for `patience` consecutive epochs*, and also retain all features of `EarlyStopping`, may I suggest this:

```py
class MyEarlyStopping(EarlyStopping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.baseline_attained = False

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if not self.baseline_attained:
            current = self.get_monitor_value(logs)
            if current is None:
                return

            if self.monitor_op(current, self.baseline):
                if self.verbose > 0:
                    print('Baseline attained.')
                self.baseline_attained = True
            else:
                return

        super(MyEarlyStopping, self).on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
```